# How to re-apply a directive containing interpolation in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ng-animate

Let's say you have a simple animation directive for slide-in:

```
directives.directive('slideIn', function () {
    return {
        compile:function (elm) {
            $(elm).css('padding-left', '200em');
            return function (scope, elm, attrs) {
                $(elm).animate({ 'padding-left':'0em'}, 500);
            };
        }
    };
});
```

And html:

```
<div slide-in>foo</div>
```

Works great.

Now let's say the html uses Angular interpolation:

```
<div slide-in>{{foo}}</div>
```

This works on the first change to the value of scope.foo, but not on subsequent attempts.

**Question is:  How to reapply the directive on each change?**

Seems like putting this in a link function with a watch is the way to go...

Comment: Search google for animation support in angular. You may not need a directive for this.

Comment: What version of Angular are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your app start, Angular go throw all Dom and **compile** all directive. You see animation once because angular compile once. You seems right, you should do it with $watch.

Here is a solution: http://jsfiddle.net/pbucv/12/

```
.directive('slideIn', function () {
    return {
        link: function (scope, elm, attrs) {
            scope.$watch("foo", function() {
                $(elm).css('padding-left', '200em');
                $(elm).animate({ 'padding-left':'0em'}, 500);
            })
        }
    };
});
```

If you want use this approach for do animation, you should learn about Angular animation. If you use Angular 1.2 here is good article about it http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/08/remastered-animation-in-angularjs-1-2.html